# How to stream a video file from a amazon server using gstreamer to the internet

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp

I have found the way to stream the `videotestsrc` element to the internet by calling these functions in the test-video.c file of gst-rtsp-server examples directory:

```
gst_rtsp_server_set_address(server,"10.xxx.xx.xxx");
gst_rtsp_server_set_service(server,"8555");
```

and unblocking the ports in the aws console.

But now replacing `videotestsrc` with the following in test-video.c, like below:

```
gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch (factory, "( "
  "filesrc location=/home/ubuntu/DELTA.mpg ! mpeg2dec ! x264enc ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 "
  ")");
```

I am not able to get the stream visible on the vlc player.

Trying the below command produces following output:

```
ubuntu@ip-xx-xxx-xx-xxx:~/gst-rtsp-server-1.2.3/examples$ /usr/local/bin/gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=rtsp://10.xxx.xx.xxx:8555/test
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Progress: (open) Opening Stream
Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtsp://10.185.10.118:8555/test
Progress: (open) Retrieving server options
Progress: (open) Retrieving media info
Progress: (request) SETUP stream 0
Progress: (open) Opened Stream
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
Progress: (request) Sent PLAY request

(lt-test-video1:9027): GLib-CRITICAL **: unblock_source: assertion `!SOURCE_DEST
ROYED (source)' failed
WARNING: from element /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstRTSP
Src:source: Could not read from resource.
Additional debug info:
gstrtspsrc.c(4367): gst_rtspsrc_reconnect (): /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeB
in:uridecodebin0/GstRTSPSrc:source:
Could not receive any UDP packets for 5.0000 seconds, maybe your firewall is blo
cking it. Retrying using a TCP connection.
♥handling interrupt.
Interrupt: Stopping pipeline ...
Execution ended after 0:00:22.473442001
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
ubuntu@ip-10-xxx-xx-xxx:~/gst-rtsp-server-1.2.3/examples$
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: RTSP handshake and configuration are working because it is going through the port you unblocked. On the other hand, your RTP communication is failing. Note the failure right after `PLAY` command. I guess you should play with `gst-launch` syntax and define source ports where RTSP client will grab video/audio from, and unblock these ports as well on your server.